# How to add checkboxes into cell using google sheets api v4

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

Is this is real or i just didn't find it in documentation?
And how i can fill only column with checkboxes?

Answer (score 5):

I found it. It's look like that:

```
service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body={
    'requests':
        [
            {
                'repeatCell':
                    {
                        'cell': {'dataValidation': {'condition': {'type': 'BOOLEAN'}}},
                        'range': {'sheetId': 0, 'startRowIndex': 1, 'endRowIndex': added_branches + 1,
                                  'startColumnIndex': 4,
                                  'endColumnIndex': 5},
                        'fields': 'dataValidation'
                    }
            },
            {

            },
        ]
}).execute()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Eugene, you can do this without a script.

See [this article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7684717?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) in the Google Sheets documentation.

Good luck.

Addendum 10/20/18:

Here is the text of that Google Link:

**Insert checkboxes**

1. On your computer, open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
2. Select the cells you want to have checkboxes.
3. In the menu at the top, click **Insert > Checkbox**.
4. To remove checkboxes, select the checkboxes you want to remove and press **Delete**.

**Note**: You can use checkboxes with charts, filters, pivot tables, and functions.

---

**Add custom checkbox values**

You can add checkboxes with custom values. For example, the custom checked value could be "Yes," and the unchecked value could be "No."

1. On your computer, open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
2. Select the cells you want to have checkboxes.
3. In the menu at the top, click **Data > Data validation**.
4. Next to "Criteria," choose **Checkbox**.
5. Click **Use custom cell values**.
6. Next to "Checked," enter a value.
7. Optional: Next to "Unchecked," enter a value.
8. Click **Save**.

Comment: Hi Erik, could you summarize what's at the article in the body of the post, please?  While it is a Google support document, links still occasionally go stale and the information would be lost otherwise.  Thanks!

Comment: jonsca, I have brought over and formatted the information from that link. If you were the person who down-voted me over sharing information in a way that wasn't your preference, now that I have edited the post, please consider upvoting. And if not ... c'est la vie.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to edit the post!  I was not the original downvoter.

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but the reason can be, that OP explicitly mentioned "using google sheets api v4". Maybe he knows what you said, but wanted to make programmatically. However, your answer is helpful for beginner.